# How to retrieve information from Java.Net.NetworkInterface

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mono

I'm using this way to try to get local ip adress of the device

```
Java.Util.IEnumeration networkInterfaces = Java.Net.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces;

                            while (networkInterfaces.HasMoreElements)
                            {
                                Java.Net.NetworkInterface netInterface =

                     (Java.Net.NetworkInterface)networkInterfaces.NextElement();
                                Console.WriteLine(netInterface.ToString());


                            }
```

This method Output is :

```
[lo][1][/::1%1%1][/127.0.0.1]

[dummy0][2]

[sit0][3]

[ip6tnl0][4]

[wlan0][5][/fe80::8e77:12ff:fe5a:6052%wlan0%5][/192.168.100.135]

[ppp0][6][/10.0.0.1]
```

How to use regex to match only this string starting with `[wlan0]` and get from groups only the ipv4 adress in C# ?

`[wlan0][28][/fe80::244:55ff:fe64:1619%wlan0%28][/192.168.88.43]`

Comment: why don't you just use the individual properties of the class instead of trying to regex the output of ToString()?  https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Java.Net.NetworkInterface/

Comment: @Jason , because except `[wlan0]` should get ip's for other interfaces in that while loop , but if i understand how to get that first i will be able to get all of they...